# Unity: collision matrix is setup but collider still triggers

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I wanted to setup the layers that my Player interacts to, but it still triggers with unwanted layers.
I have disabled whole collision matrix in project settings:

[image]

Here's my Player settings:

[image]

And ProjectileCleaner settings:

[image]

I have next script attached to 'Player' gameObject, but my Player still triggers with 'ProjectileCleaner' layer. Why?

```
public class PlayerCollisionController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("trigger: " + other.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the layer collision matrix only affects (physical) collision detection, and trigger related callbacks will always be called, if you don't care about them, just ignore them.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("ProjectileCleaner"))
        return;
}
```